# Got TLS cert, ,Route53, ALB, and EC2 all ready but browser is blocking part of my website for mixed-content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-certificate-manager, aws-alb

So we have this project due tonight. We have sat up all necessary AWS services using Terraform except for the TLS cert part. we have EC2, Route53, ALB, VPC. everything is working good but once we try to access our website, the browser blocks part. the browser shows that the cert  is there and valid. our ALB conf is that we redirect http to https and from https to our EC2. in EC2, our vhost file for apache has both 80 and 443. we can not figure out where the problem exactly is.

this is our domain-name, git-legion.dev

we tried on all different browsers and they all show that the cert is there but they  are blocking part of the website because there is a mixed content.

[image: This is our alb listenrs conf]

This is how our website should look like

[image: This is how our website should look like]

But this is how browsers show it

[image: this is how browsers show it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the document returned by that url (after subsequent redirects), you'll see that a few of the resources have http://` urls.

```
$ curl -sL https://git-legion.dev | grep -F 'http://'
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://git-legion.dev/js/plugins/select2/select2.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://git-legion.dev/css/dist/all.css?id=98db4e9b7650453c8b00">
                            <a href="http://git-legion.dev/setup" class="bs-wizard-dot"></a>
                            <a href="http://git-legion.dev/setup/migrate" class="bs-wizard-dot"></a>
                            <a href="http://git-legion.dev/setup/user" class="bs-wizard-dot"></a>
                                  <form action="http://git-legion.dev/setup/migrate" method="GET">
              <script src="http://git-legion.dev/js/dist/all.js?id=bf1b244d8cc9096e4a18" nonce="yn3lThimgEBlyTMj1FLCFRAIdVJuDCEYhXzPBNRD"></script>
                    url: "http://git-legion.dev/setup/mailtest",
```

That's why the browser refuses to access them, because the original connection was secure, but these other resources are not.  There's no one answer on how best to build these URLs, but your application framework should be able to help you.

Comment: yes you are right, it all was fixed from our application in EC2. thank you dude!!